# Create ascending groups based on consecutive sequence of numbers

Tags: r, logic, sequence

I'm looking for a way to create ascending groups ($B) based on an sequence of numbers ($A).  This is easy to do in excel by writing a new column with a logical statement like "if A = 1, then add B+1, else B" (assuming that the first group in A begins with a 1) but I haven't figured out how to do it in R.  Thanks in advance.

```
A    B
1    1
2    1
3    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
1    3
2    3
1    4
```

Comment: `df$B = cumsum(df$A == 1)`

Comment: @Psidom How would you create B from A?